# OnNavigatedTo and OnNavigatedFrom in WP8.1 using MVVMLight (Silverlight)

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, mvvm-light

I have a problem while navigating pages in my WP8.1 Silverlight application. When I was using standard CodeBehind approach everything was simple, because implementing `OnNavigatedTo` was enough.

Now I want to handle `OnNavigatedTo` and `OnNavigatedFrom` events in ViewModel. I started with standard `RelayCommand` approach.

ViewModel code:

```
private RelayCommand initializeVideoRecorderCommand;
public RelayCommand InitializeVideoRecorderCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (initializeVideoRecorderCommand == null)
        {
            initializeVideoRecorderCommand = new RelayCommand(InitializeVideoRecorder);
        }
        return initializeVideoRecorderCommand;
    }
}
private void InitializeVideoRecorder()
{
    //Initialization code goes here
}
```

`InitializeVideoRecorderCommand` should now be bind to `OnNavigatedTo` event. I managed to do this with help from [Vovich](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18297371/wp-mvvm-navigation-onnavigatedto) (I only had to change `xmlns:cmd` namespace, because Visual coudn't find `GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras` assembly).

XAML code:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity" 
    xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Platform"
    DataContext="{Binding Camera, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger>
            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding InitializeVideoRecorderCommand}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <!-- Rest of the UI -->
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

`InitializeVideoRecorder` function is triggered when I navigate to `CameraView`.

But now I don't know how to override `OnNavigatedFrom`. I thought that little change to XAML code would do the trick.

XAML code:

```
<i:EventTrigger EventName="OnNavigatedTo">
```

But this doesn't trigger event at all.

**How can I use properly navigation events with this approach?**

Comment: Did you solve this issue`?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. But I stoped trying after my teacher said that in this case there's nothing wrong in code behind.